# IntelliJ python debugger `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'logging.handlers'; 'logging' is not a package`

Tags: python, django, debugging, intellij-idea, pycharm

While using IntelliJ with python I cannot make the debugger work *while testing* because it always appear:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'logging.handlers'; 'logging' is not a package`

[image]

Checking the Traceback I encountered the problem shown in the image below but I do not know if it really points in some direction to solve the issue:

[image]

I tried installing `logging` separately without any effect. On the other hand `logging` works perfectly in the python console.

Comment: Show us the output of this code: `import logging; print(logging.__file__)`

Comment: `/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py`

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue before, but I am unsure if this is the correct answer.
When I had this issue, I had tkinter installed but it was only installed for a different built in version of python. I managed to fix it by using my terminal and using `apt install python3-tk`, so I believe that if you are using python 3 that was installed manually, you will have to install the logging module into the python directory manually. Also make sure you are executing your file with the same version of python you are using in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a `Django tests` problem, running the tests as `Python tests` it works. `Run -> Edit` configurations.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-56591